# Is there any difference between File from file input and File created with constructor?

Tags: javascript, file, blob

The thing is - if I send file from html input to API, it's being processed properly.

However, if I try to re-create it - I mean - Im copying **every single** property from `File` object which user has uploaded, such as:

- preview
- name
- size
- type

to a native object (`const file = { ... }`) in JavaScript and then Im creating a `File` from it:

`new File([random integer], file.name, { type: file.type, preview: file.preview })` (it also has every other property which normal `File` has)

But then api doesn't accept it and says that the `type` is invalid.

What does it mean? Both of them are **visibly identical**. Every prop is exactly the same. But still if I create `File` from object, not directly from input, it's not being processed properly.

Looking forward for any feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To answer directly:

> A File object is a specific kind of a Blob, and can be used in any
>   context that a Blob can. In particular, FileReader,
>   URL.createObjectURL(), createImageBitmap(), and XMLHttpRequest.send()
>   accept both Blobs and Files.

Here are docs for Blob. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

You cannot create a binary representation by creating an object literal.

You can create a new Blob() object though.

You can look at these examples to discover how to accomplish this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Examples

**Edit**

To be clear, in your attempts to clone the `File`, the aspect of the underlying `Blob` you are missing when copying properties is the **snapshot_state**, which you do not have access to in the Javascript runtime. In order to create that state, the browser must create a new `Blob` object. [Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#blob-section)

Comment: So you say that I should send `Blob` to api instead of `File`?

Comment: No, I'm addressing your points about creating a new `File` object. If you are going to do that, you must do it properly - you cannot just copy instance properties from an existing `File` object.

Comment: The proper way to send a file or files via AJAX is through a FormData object.

Comment: I didn't address you send a file to the API because you said this: **_The thing is - if I send file from html input to API, it's being processed properly._**

Comment: The case is that im using redux store to keep my form data there, however I cant store a `File` object there because redux store cant keep anything which is not serializable (and `File` isn't) - thats why I wanted to store it as a native object and just right before the api request change it back to `File` object. Seems like I failed.

Comment: Well, you didn't disclose that. So the _real_ question is: **can we store/serialize a File/Blob object so that we can access/use the file at a later time?** - that answer is NO.

Comment: There has to be some way to deal with it... Im gna commit a suicide if not xD Thank you anyways m8

Comment: There is only one way, you can use FileReader to read the file and store the file contents with redux. If the file is text no biggie, if the file is binary, you'll need to base64 encode it. That is the only way.

Comment: Accepted file types are png and pdf with max size of 5mb. I guess it will be an overkill to encode a file weighing 5mb to base64 :(

Comment: You are absolutely correct - I would never recommend to do so. That is why I didn't mention it until your psychology became an issue :-) -- That data would all be in the heap (in memory) too - not a good scenario at all.

Comment: There is always Electron!